# How to play swf animation file from IOS browser?

Tags: ios, cordova, flash

How can I play swf animation file from IOS browser? Is there any alternative which I can use.

I know that IOS don't support but there must be some way to play. Note my swf animation has

video and audio involved.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to play SWFs on iOS. Try porting your animation to a format supported by the iOS device.

Comment: yes . i know this.. but how should i port my animation to a format suppoterd by IOS

Comment: Why don't you export it to a video format that runs on iOS? Does the animation take any user interaction (you click stuff in the SFW to make things happen)?

Comment: @saikat If you want help converting your swf file you should change your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Convert your swf files to HTML 5  see this - http://googlecode.blogspot.in/2011/06/swiffy-convert-swf-files-to-html5.html

After converting videos to HTML 5 you can play them in iOS browser.

Here is one more free swf to html 5 converter - http://www.flash-to-html5.net/

Comment: thanks for giving the links but that will not help me to solve the problem. This is because animation has video and audio. There must be some way to show the animation for IOS users

Comment: No you can't play swf file on iOS .. you have to convert the animation to some other format such as Video or html 5 or something else which is supported by iOS